# Need assistance regarding restoring purchase items count

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am using this `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];` to restore previously purchased items, I am doing it successfully but I want a count how many items are going to restore because I have a notification that tells about successful transaction done that pops `uialertview` and that alert pops for every restore item.

With count I want to limit `restore alert` to pop only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`'s `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` method.

The documentation for `-restoreCompletedTransactions` states that:

> After the transactions are delivered, the payment queue calls the observer’s `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` method. If an error occurred while restoring transactions, the observer will be notified through its `paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:` method.

So this method will be called once after all transactions are restored, and if you temporarily disable alerts for individual transactions while restoring them, everything will be fine.